# Is there a trick for using TSQLMonitor with a TSQLConnection that uses the new ODBC dbExpress driver?

Tags: t-sql, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I have been testing the new ODBC dbExpress driver that ships with Delphi XE2, and have noticed that the TSQLMonitor does not seem to work. Thinking that I may have configured the component incorrectly, I hooked up a TSQLMonitor to a TSQLConnection that uses the MS SQL dbExpress driver, and that worked like a charm.

I don't see any posts about this problem on the Web. Has anyone else noticed this issue? Does it appear to be a bug, an unsupported feature (no monitoring on a TSQLConnection that uses the ODBC driver), or is there a trick to configuring the TSQLMonitor under this condition?

Comment: Did you try using the Tracing derived driver? This adds to the SQLMonitor results and might end up being useful. If the ODBC driver is a fully native driver (as I think) it might not work the same as the "old" Dll-based drivers....

Comment: Marco: That is a great suggestion. After wiring the TSQLConnection to the ODBC driver, and then expanding the Driver property of the TSQLConnection, I set the driver's DelegateConnection property to DBXTrace. Then I expanded the DelegateConnection property and set TraceFile to True and TraceFile to a file name (all as per your suggestions). Thank you for this workaround. I still want to see if anyone knows how to address the TSQLMonitor problem.

Comment: @Marco Cantù: A bit of topic but please can you consider this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147850/add-my-own-items-to-delphi-ide-insight-f6-with-in-delphi-open-tools-api)?

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of these links, but just in case I'll post them here.
:)                                                                  
[Tutorial: Using TSQLMonitor with an ODBC Connection](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Tutorial:_Using_TSQLMonitor_with_an_ODBC_Connection)

[Debugging dbExpress Applications using TSQLMonitor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Debugging_dbExpress_Applications_using_TSQLMonitor)

Comment: @Mike, your comment sounds like an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out:**

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    Connect;
    SQLMonitor1.SQLConnection := SQLConnection1;
    SQLMonitor1.Active := True;
    ExecuteQueries;
    SQLMonitor1.SaveToFile('D:\\Log.txt');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Exception ocurred!: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Connect;
begin
  SQLConnection1 := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
  SQLConnection1.ConnectionName := 'odbcinterbaseconnection';
  SQLConnection1.LoginPrompt := False;
  SQLConnection1.LoadParamsOnConnect := True;
  SQLConnection1.Connected := True;
end;

procedure TForm2.ExecuteQueries;
var
  Query: String;
begin
  try
    if SQLConnection1.Connected then
    begin
      Query := 'CREATE TABLE ExampleTable(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50))';
      SQLConnection1.Execute(Query, nil);
      Query := 'INSERT INTO ExampleTable VALUES(1,''test1'')';
      SQLConnection1.Execute(Query, nil);
      Query := 'INSERT INTO ExampleTable VALUES(2,''test2'')';
      SQLConnection1.Execute(Query, nil);
      Query := 'INSERT INTO ExampleTable VALUES(3,''test3'')';
      SQLConnection1.Execute(Query, nil);
      Query := 'SELECT * FROM ExampleTable';
      SQLConnection1.Execute(Query, nil);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Exception ocurred!: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```