# Add my own items to Delphi IDE Insight (F6) with in Delphi Open Tools API

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, toolsapi

I want to use `INTAIDEINsightService` perhaps `AddItem` or `AddActionList` to add an entry to the IDE insight feature in Delphi.

According to the Delphi OTA wiki,  `INTAIDEINsightService`  allows you to register your own action. The only reference I can find is [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Tools_API_Changes_for_XE), which mentions the name of the API, and that it exists at all. There is nothing in the Delphi help about it.  The `ToolsAPI.pas` unit in Delphi XE shows two methods in this interface that let you register actions:

```
function AddActionList(  Actions: TCustomActionList; ... ): Integer;
procedure RemoveActionList(const Index: Integer);
```

The comments say "Items will be shown as[Description |] Category | TCustomAction.Caption.       Contained actions which do not specify a category will not be shown.".

I haven't been able to find any other documentation or samples using actions.  A simple "hello world" example where an action, or just an item,  is registered with description or category "helloworld", that is then searchable and shows up when you hit F6 would be perfect, but Actions are preferred.

It looks like such a wizard would have to implement `INTAIDEInsightItem` in order to render itself inside the IDE insight, but I'm not sure if that's "required" for a hello-world sample or not.  I'm not really sure if you have to use actions, or if regular "item" adds are sufficient.

(My ultimate goal is to create a new gExperts-style expert to "open any unit in my library path by searching for it by name using IDE insight" but I'll start with adding unit names to the ide insight one item at a time.)

Comment: (Marco Cantu's Delphi 2010 book, sample code for chapter 1 includes a sample without Actions -- got it working in XE. If Marco Cantu happens to be a stackoverflow user, it would be more than fair if he were to answer this question...   But I would still love to hear if anyone has gotten ACTIONS working with IDE insight. )

Comment: Marco's code is here: http://code.marcocantu.com/p/marcodelphibooks/source/tree/HEAD/delphi2010handbook/01/CustomInsight

Comment: Why remove toolsapi tag david?

Comment: Warren, when i have questions about the OTA most of time I found the answer digging in the source of the [CNPACK](http://code.google.com/p/cnpack/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%253Fstate%253Dclosed) or [Gexperts](http://gexperts.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gexperts/trunk/)

Comment: For sure [Marco Cantù](http://stackoverflow.com/users/45145/marco-cantu) is on Stackoverflow. I have forwarded your wish to him :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following shows category 'Hello' under 'Commands':

[image: IDE Insight screenshot]

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, ActnList, ImgList, Controls;

type
  TDataModule1 = class(TDataModule)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    ActionHello: TAction;
    procedure ActionHelloExecute(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  DataModule1: TDataModule1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  ToolsAPI, Dialogs;

procedure TDataModule1.ActionHelloExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello, world!');
end;

var
  Index: Integer = -1;

initialization
  DataModule1 := TDataModule1.Create(nil);
  Index := (BorlandIDEServices as INTAIDEInsightService).AddActionList(DataModule1.ActionList1);

finalization
  if Index <> -1 then
    (BorlandIDEServices as INTAIDEInsightService).RemoveActionList(Index);
  FreeAndNil(DataModule1);

end.
```

The dfm is simply a datamodule with an action list, image list and an action:

```
object DataModule1: TDataModule1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Left = 218
  Top = 134
  Height = 215
  Width = 306
  object ActionList1: TActionList
    Images = ImageList1
    Left = 24
    Top = 16
    object ActionHello: TAction
      Category = 'Hello'
      Caption = 'Hello, World!'
      ImageIndex = 0
      OnExecute = ActionHelloExecute
    end
  end
  object ImageList1: TImageList
    Left = 88
    Top = 16
    Bitmap = {
      494C010101000C000C0010001000FFFFFFFFFF10FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF424D3600
      0000000000003600000028000000400000001000000001002000000000000010
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000800080008000800086868600000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000008000800080008000FFFFFF00FFFFFF00C0C0C000868686000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000
      800080008000FFFFFF00FFFFFF000000000000000000C0C0C000C0C0C0008686
      8600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000868686008000800080008000FFFF
      FF00FFFFFF000000000000000000800080008000800000000000C0C0C000C0C0
      C000868686000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000008686860080008000FFFFFF000000
      000000000000800080008000800080008000800080008000800000000000C0C0
      C000C0C0C0008686860000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000008686860000000000000000008000
      800080008000800080000080800000FFFF008000800080008000800080000000
      0000C0C0C000C0C0C00086868600000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000008686860080008000800080008000
      8000800080008000800080008000008080008000800080008000800080008000
      800000000000C0C0C00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080008000FFFFFF008000
      80008000800080008000800080008000800000FFFF0000FFFF00800080008000
      8000800080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080008000FFFF
      FF0080008000800080008000800080008000800080000080800000FFFF0000FF
      FF00800080008000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000
      8000FFFFFF00800080008000800080008000008080008000800000FFFF0000FF
      FF00800080008000800080008000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000080008000FFFFFF00800080008000800000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF008000
      8000800080008000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000080008000FFFFFF00800080008000800080008000800080008000
      8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000080008000FFFFFF008000800080008000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000800080008000800000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000424D3E000000000000003E000000
      2800000040000000100000000100010000000000800000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00FFFF000000000000FE3F000000000000
      F81F000000000000E00F00000000000080070000000000000003000000000000
      0001000000000000000000000000000000010000000000008001000000000000
      C001000000000000E000000000000000F000000000000000F803000000000000
      FC0F000000000000FE3F00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000}
  end
end
```

Here I leave the optional parameters `Description` and `Category` of the `AddActionList` method the default empty strings which ends up as '**Commands**' and the value of `Category` from the action list but you can specify your own values which will override these defaults.